# Diode SPICE data accuracy at high frequencies?

Tags: rf, diodes, antenna, simulation, spice

I'm trying to do a non-linear harmonic balance simulation on a schottky diode model MACOM [MA4E1317](https://cdn.macom.com/datasheets/MA4Exxxx%20Series.pdf) that according to the manufacturer is usable up to 80 GHz. I got the SPICE data and S-Parameter files from the manufacturer and use Microwave Office AWR to do the simulations.
As I am doing large signal S-parameter simulations at 35 GHz I have read in the literature that packaging parasitics and pad inductances will greatly affect the performance of the circuit at these frequencies.
If I just the SPICE data is it going to be accurate for a harmonic balance simulation at 35 GHz? If not, how do I make sure I am accounting for parasitics at this frequency?

[image]

Comment: 'large signal' and 'S-parameter' aren't really compatible, the latter is measured with a single frequency, and is no more than a describing function if harmonics are present. Agilent/Keysight have a thing dubbed [X-parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-parameters), which they allege extend S-Parameters into the large signal domain, making them usable for harmonic balance. At 35 GHz you will certainly need to take package parasitics into account. Are your S-Parameters and SPICE parameters of the bare die or the packaged part?

Comment: We know that the wavelength is of the order of 8mm... Ex: if a coax has a capacitance of 101pf/m, 1mm of length would give a capacitance of 0.1pF which is greater than the capacitance of 0.045 measured pF of the junction... Clearly any connection will impact the characteristics of the component...unless you "control" them wisely. You need also knowing "where" these parameters were measured...

Comment: If you signed an NDA to get those SPICE parameters, I'd be wary of posting it here.  Regardless, if that's all they gave you, it's a very basic model and doesn't include any package parasitics at all.  I would ask MACOM if they can provide that info to you if they haven't yet.  Using the model without the parasitics is pretty worthless for a part intended for use in high-frequency applications.  Oh yea, and the `Cto` is a typo.  Should be `Cjo` or `Cj0`.

Comment: Oh, whoops.  After looking at the datasheet, they give a value for \$C_J\$ and \$C_T\$.  You could just use the capacitance they give you in that SPICE parameter chart as the value for `Cjo`...but it might be more accurate if you use the 0.020pF datasheet value for `Cjo` and in the simulation add an extra explicit capacitor across the diode of 0.027pF so it adds up to 0.047pF. The point of doing this is the junction capacitance is non-linear, whereas the explicit one is linear.  Anyway, my point still stands to ask MACOM instead of making a bunch of assumptions.

Comment: Here some explanation about "reference" planes (for defining exactly where parameters are measured) https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/373153D-01/vnahelp/reference_plane/#:~:text=In%20a%20VNA%20measurement%2C%20the,device%20under%20test%20(DUT). See also this https://www.keysight.com/be/en/solutions/measurement-fundamentals/network-analysis.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extrapolate Spice data where geometric impedances affect the conductance and junction capacitance assumptions in the datasheet.

"Measured at a LO frequency of 9.375 GHz, with an IF frequency of 300 MHz"

Maxwell, and other tools are needed to apply Gauss's Law, Faraday's Law and Lenz's Law others with the parasitic inductance capacitance and effective permittivity reduction with frequency.  Fundamentals learnt in school and observed in the best products in the industry will help you start along with some research papers which might are useful but not as useful as commercial solutions.

If you belong to a company with potential large sales, the best avenue is through your buyer, who goes thru to distributor to customer tech/eng support with a specific request. Or email MACOM support.